# create a changeset during staging ETL to Microsoft MDS for approval

Tags: master-data-services, mds, master-data-management

In MDS, if i manually make changes, I can create a changeset for approval.  Is there a way to force approvals for changes that come in via the staging tables?  if so, How?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cheat.  You could create an entity with approval required that you use as a staging table.  Since this "staging" table is actually an entity, it would have an approval workflow automatically.

When the changeset for this "staging" entity is approved, you can have it create a changeset on the REAL entity via something like exec mdm.udpEntityMemberChangesetSave.